Bridge psychic bid without looking at cards
If someone opens 1 Club without looking at their cards, is this legal in duplicate bridge? I suspect that this could be considered a psychic bid, but I'm not sure.
Someone at our friendly club game has done this several times. The opponents said that this isn't allowed.
We don't have an official director anymore. When we had a director, we followed ACBL rules. A few of us know the rules fairly well, but this is beyond our knowledge.
A psychic bid probably has no place in our friendly game, but that is a different issue.

First, yes, it is illegal (it wasn't at one time.  This is why it is now).  Law 7B2:

Each player counts their cards face down to be sure there are exactly thirteen; after that, and before making a call, must inspect the faces of the cards.

Is blind bidding a psychic call?  It's arguable, but I'd say no.  A psychic is a deliberate and gross misstatement of one's agreement.  It's hard to say that this is a deliberate misstatement - after all, it could be exactly what their hand has.  But also, the partnership could agree (if it weren't for 7B2) that "as dealer, 1D shows 0-37 points, 13 cards, at least zero of which are diamonds" - and if so, blind bidding 1D would be a correct match to your agreement.  Now, there's no regulating authority that allows that agreement, and I wouldn't recommend your game be the first, but it wouldn't be psychic.
But that's not relevant here.  One joker thinks it's fun, and the rest of the game doesn't.  And it's a violation of Law. If your game wants to follow the Laws, well, this is one of them.  And it's a "must" law, "the strongest word, a serious matter indeed" (Introduction).  I'm not sure what the penalty for the first violation of this would be were it my game, but the second would come with "it's not funny, it's not legal, your game is over, you can come back in a month."

Regardless of, and in addition to, specific Laws applying to this situation, such a call is EXTREMELY unethical: it tells caller's partner that the bid made was meaningless, which is both blatant and deliberate provision of unauthorized information to partner. I would award 1 full board penalty for a first offense (with average plus for the other pair), and expulsion from the game accompanied by a 1 month suspension from the club for any second offense.
I have been a Certified ACBL Director since 1974 - though it is many years since I practiced as such.
In making such a determination, I am guided by law 91:

While my decision to suspend the offending Player or Partnership is appealable to the Tournament Organizer (here, the elected executive or equivalent of the Club), my disciplinary penalties for the first and second offense are not. Such blatant disregard for the enjoyment of other players, and the long established ethics of the game, simply cannot be allowed to stand.
Laws of Duplicate Bridge (Revised 2017)

Update from Comment response below:
@ArcanistLupus: Is is necessary - but very far from sufficient - that Opponents receive all information about the bidding that Partner has. It is also required that the ONLY information Partner receives from a call or play is the actual call made or card played. All variations from this are Unauthorized Information. From Law 16 (B) (1):

Any extraneous information from partner that might suggest a call or play is unauthorized. This includes ..., special emphasis, ..., gesture, movement or mannerism.

Here, the act of calling without looking at one's cards suggests that Partner Pass, rather than making a minimum response. The act of deliberately, in front of all players, calling before looking at one's cards is all of "special emphasis, gesture, movement, [and] mannerism."

Is it possible to explain to a non-bridge player why this is unethical? It doesn't seem like you're giving your partner any information that you're not also giving your opponents

While this is the answer that I was hoping for, you haven't explained why this is unauthorized information to the partner.

@ArcanistLupus: Is is necessary - but very far from sufficient - that Opponents receive all information about the bidding that Partner has. It is also required that the ONLY information Partner receives from a call or play is the actual call made or card played. All variations from this are Unauthorized Information. From Law 16 (B) (1): " Any extraneous information from partner that might suggest a call or play is unauthorized." Here, the act of calling without looking at one's cards suggests that Partner Pass, rather than making a minimum response.

Is there a game that plays similarly to Bridge but where things like this are explicitly allowed?

@KarlKnechtel: In my youth, we would sometimes get together for drunken Friday night games that specified "anything goes". For an ambitious and relatively balanced group, this can be useful training. However, the game is definitely NOT Contract Bridge. The essence of any true partnership game is that ethics will matter, as that is what makes the game interesting. If you are interested in a completely cut-throat trick taking game, try Sergeant-Major (also called 9-5-2). It's another, this time three handed, whist variant without ethical constraints as there are no partnerships.

I would point to Law 74:

LAW 74
CONDUCT AND ETIQUETTE
A. Proper Attitude

A player should maintain a courteous attitude at all times.
A player should carefully avoid any remark or extraneous action that might cause annoyance or embarrassment to another player or might
interfere with the enjoyment of the game.
Every player should follow uniform and correct procedure in calling and playing.

B. Etiquette As a matter of courtesy a player should
refrain from:

paying insufficient attention to the game.
making gratuitous comments during the auction and play.
detaching a card before it is his turn to play.
prolonging play unnecessarily (as in playing on although he knows that all the tricks are surely his) for the purpose of disconcerting
an opponent.
summoning and addressing the Director in a manner discourteous to him or to other contestants.

C. Violations of Procedure The following
are examples of violations of procedure:

using different designations for the same call.
indicating approval or disapproval of a call or play.
indicating the expectation or intention of winning or losing a trick that has not been completed.
commenting or acting during the auction or play so as to call attention to a significant occurrence, or to the number of tricks
still required for success.
looking intently at any other player during the auction and play, or at another player’s hand as for the purpose of seeing his cards or
of observing the place from which he draws a card (but it is
appropriate to act on information acquired by unintentionally seeing
an opponent’s card23).
showing an obvious lack of further interest in a deal (as by folding one’s cards).
varying the normal tempo of bidding or play for the purpose of disconcerting an opponent.
leaving the table needlessly before the round is called.


I think in particular 74.B.1 and 74.C.6 are relevant examples that indicate that bidding without looking at the cards is an infraction.
